# How to get top scores or scores adjacent to player's using Facebook Scores API?

Tags: facebook-graph-api

This seems to be the only endpoint in Facebook Graph API for getting scores for an app using Game Services.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/reference/v2.5/app/scores

The only way to build one list of top scorers and another list of those adjacent to player's score (among player's friends) seems to be to get whole list and then process it yourself.

Since these two must be pretty common use cases, has anybody found another way to do this?

I am trying to do this using iOS SDK but if there is a way to do this, it should be adaptable to any platform.

Edited: Forgot to mention that the reason I think getting whole list to do this might not be most efficient way is the possibility of huge friend's lists for a popular game. Although that does not apply to my game yet, but might someday in future, ha ha.